# Linux Shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I modified a bash_profile of "oracle" user. As I swith user from root to oracle user by

```
#su - oracle
```

it will ask for user input by displaying below statement

```
Select Version of Oracle [10G or 11G]:
```

Is there any way , If am not providing Input lets say for 5 seconds or 10 seconds it must take any default value; lets say either 10G or 11G. whatever I have mentioned in the code it should wait for input for 5/10 seconds if not provided by user code should provide automatically the default value. How can we handle this in the code.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: This Is what I coded in .bash_profile. It will ask for Version of Oracle.So can we just wait and force to set a default value if user is taking more than 5/10 seconds **********************************************************************# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
echo -n "Select Version of Oracle [10G or 11G]:"
read Oversion
version=$(echo $Oversion | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
if [ "$version" = "10G" ]
then
ORACLE_BASE=/data1/oracle10g; export ORACLE_BASE
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PAT
echo $version

Comment: As a user, I would prefer that you pick a default, assign it, emit a message indicating that it has been assigned, and let me take an action to change it if desired.  Timed out interaction in a .bashrc is as annoying as confirmation pop-up windows or clippy.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -n "Oracle version (10g/11g)? "
read -t 10 VERSION || VERSION="10g"
echo $VERSION
```

[For reference - bash `read` command](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

read -t 10 -p "Select Version of Oracle [10G or 11G]:" version

if [ "$version" = "10G" || "$version" = "10g" ]
then
    ORACLE_BASE=/data1/oracle10g
fi
export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
echo $version
```